# How to set sessions in laravel controller and display sessions in the views blade?

Tags: laravel, session, view

I want to set my errors as a session and display that errors from the session in the views blade template. How should I do this?

Controller code is :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'donator_first_name' => 'required|alpha|max:50',
    'donator_email'      => 'required|string',
]);



if ($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('errors', 'hey');
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->messages())->withInput();

        }
```

views blade template code is:

@if($errors)

```
    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
        {{dd($message)}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.15 @RossWilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `Session` facade, you can use the `->withErrors($validator)` redirect method ([see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators)).

Your code will look like the following:

```
...

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
    }

...
```

To display errors use:

```
@if($errors)
    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
        {{ $message }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: how to display the errors then? Is it {{$vaidator}} ? @thrsiskelvin

Comment: Doesn't display anything in the view. @thisiskelvin

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai See update. the `//` was used as an example of what should be used. I've changed to `{{ $message }}`.

Comment: Can you `dd()` instead the if validator fails to see if errors are being passed.

Comment: Yes I tried dd. It doesn't show $message . That means it does not go inside the if condition.

Comment: {{dd($errors->all())}} this is displayed as empty [ ]. @thrsiskelvin

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai To test this, are you create an error to be shown?

Comment: yes. I entered the first name with numbers exapmple, rocky21. which should fail because my rule includes 'required|alpha|max:50' .

Comment: Can you paste all the code in your question to see how this is being done.